# Detect double taps in ViewHolder class of RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to create a OnDoubleTapListener to detect double tabs on the imageView(selectedImage) within the viewholder class below. Something similar to the setOnLongClickListener in the code. 
The recycleView adapter itself is set within a fragment.

I have seen various ways of doing this within a fragment but I am trying to keep implementation within the adapter.

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var selectedImage: ImageView
        var textTitle: TextView
        var textDescription: TextView

        init {
            selectedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSelected)
            textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle)
            textDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDescription)

            selectedImage.setOnLongClickListener {
               doSomeThing()
              true
          }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a GestureListener inner class that extends SimpleOnGestureListener within the ViewHolder.

To make only 'selectedImage' respond to the 'onDoubleTap' that I overbid in GestureListener, I had 'selectedImage' implement setOnTouchListener and pass in event to GestureDetector.

```
 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var selectedImage: ImageView
        var textTitle: TextView
        var textDescription: TextView
        var gDetector: GestureDetector? = null

      init {
            selectedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSelected)
            textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle)
            textDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDescription)
            gDetector = GestureDetector(selectedImage.context, GestureListener())

            selectedImage.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                gDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
                true
            }
        }

   inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
               //doSomething
                return true
            }
        }
```